# subprocess python passing files as arguments

Tags: python, string, arguments, subprocess

I have to run a simple exernal programm inside a python script, passing some arguments and some files.
I tried outside of the script and it is working corretly.
The problem is that I don't know why the external programm is not working correctly when I run inside a python script.
I think that the problem is in how I'm writing the name of the files inside the arguments. I tried every different combinations.

I'm using subprocess, Python 3.6 and Windows

```
> import subprocess
> 
> software=str(r"C:\Program Files\aa\bin\aa.exe")
> 
> c=subprocess.call([software,'-db', '–if "File_assembly.cxm"', '–of
> "File_assembly_dec.cxm"'], shell=True)
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.
I'm destroyed!
Cheers,
Carlo

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the full path to the file.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running in the same folder, so it not that problem.I tried in any case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With subprocess call you eiter pass the command with shell=True as string:

```
subprocess.call(software + ' -db –if "File_assembly.cxm" –of "File_assembly_dec.cxm"', shell=True)
```

or without as list if shell=False:

```
c=subprocess.call([software,'-db', '–if', '"File_assembly.cxm"', '–of', '"File_assembly_dec.cxm"'])
```

See documentation for more info: [subprocess.call()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: Thanks @Yassine . The first command dones't work. I had an error in retourn, the second seems to work in Python, but the second software can't read properly the command. I have to work a little on it. Thanks again.